# Subject-verb (dis)agreement

Tags: translation

The following excerpt is from David Precht's *Erkenne die Welt* (p. 53); he is quoting the pre-Socratic philosopher Anaximenes:

> "Wie unsere Seele, die Luft ist, uns regiert", meint Anaximenes, "so
> umfasst auch den ganzen Kosmos Hauch und Luft."

I cannot figure out the subject of *umfasst*.  Its conjugation suggests that this subject is singular, but *Hauch und Luft* would be plural.  The other possibility, *Kosmos*, is ruled out by being in the accusative case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hauch und Luft können aufgefasst werden als eine Sache, die unterschiedlich, vielleicht weil vage, dargestellt wird.

> Hier regiert Not und Elend

wäre ein analoger Fall.

Comment: I would add that this kind of thing is not normally allowed, but apparently there's an exception when the pair is taken to be a single entity in two parts. I'm struggling to think of a similar example in English; "Our top priority at the moment is food and water" perhaps. But note that USA is singular in English, but plural in German (which makes more sense).